# How to get column under the title in DynamicReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

[image]

I need to get the column right under the title and i don't need any gaps in between. And how to set width to the column? I have given `setWidth(50)` but its not getting and the border is covering entire right side of the page

Here is my code:

```
public class DynamicReport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report
        StyleBuilder plainStyle = stl.style().setFontName("FreeUniversal");

        StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style(plainStyle).bold().setBorder(stl.pen1Point());
        StyleBuilder col1style = stl.style().setBorder(stl.pen1Point());

        report
          .title(Components.text("Tax Invoice Cum Delivery Challan").setStyle(boldStyle)
          .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
          .columns(col.column("", "companyName", type.stringType()).setWidth(50).setStyle(col1style))
          .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
          .setDataSource("SELECT companyName FROM marketing_database.company_profile", 
                                      connection);
        try {
            report.show();
            report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream("c:/report.pdf"));
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

Any help in this will be appreciated

**UPDATED:**

I got how to set the width for a column. I used this code:

```
 col.column("", "companyName", type.stringType()).setFixedWidth(20)
```

Comment: You can post your solution as the answer

Comment: @AlexK I have two problems.One is setting width and other is no gap between title and column.i have solved the width issue.But no gap issue is still there.So i cant be able to post the answer

Comment: Did you try to set height for bands (Detail and ColumnHeader)? Try to set Detail band height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
report



        .columnHeader(//title of the report


              Components.text("Tax Invoice Cum Delivery Challan").setStyle(boldStyle).setFixedHeight(10)
              .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))

             .columns(
                     col.column("", "companyName", type.stringType()).setFixedWidth(200).setStyle(col1style))

              .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())//show page number on the page footer
              .setDataSource("SELECT companyName FROM marketing_database.company_profile", 
                                      connection);

        try {
                    //show the report
            report.show();

                    //export the report to a pdf file
            report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream("c:/report.pdf"));
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```